# Cakephp : trying to implement Google maps

Tags: google-maps, cakephp, google-maps-api-3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am new to Cakephp 2.3 and trying to implement a Google maps on my app ..i have downloaded the helper from here

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/marcferna/2012/09/08/google_maps_helper

i followed the instructions but dont know why my maps are not showing on the page ...

here is what i have done

**Controller**

```
 class  LocationController extends AppController{

 public $helpers = array('GoogleMap');

 public function index(){

 }

    }
```

and on my view page i did this

```
       <?php echo $this->GoogleMap->map(); ?>
```

i have change this to true and false to check if it works but didnt

```
  var $defaultLocalize = true;
```

**Page source**

[http://www.pastebin.com/aAKcAthm](http://pastebin.com/aAKcAthm)

Comment: You might also try [googlemaps-v3-helper](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/12/21/googlemapsv3-cakephp-helper/) - Not sure if the one you are using is 2.3/2.4 compatible.

Comment: ok well let me try this one too

Comment: @mark your one is little complicated .. let me setup the first one ..

Comment: either way: use Firefox + Firebug debug console to find out if there is a javascript error. If so, follow the error and try to fix whats wrong.

Comment: @mark there is not any error ..i have checked it

Comment: @mark in console there is an error coming sir that "the page ran insecure content from http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well i got the solution ... actually i have change this url

```
<?= $this->Html->script('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true', false); ?>
```

to http secure..

```
<?= $this->Html->script('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true', false); ?>
```

Comment: Hey @hellosheikh, sorry I didn't see this before. I'm the author of the [CakePHP-GoogleMapHelper](https://github.com/marcferna/CakePHP-GoogleMapHelper). It's weird that it didn't work without https, I have an example working without it... If you have any other problems, don't hesitate to ask here or in the github page.

Comment: okk i will .. but at that time when i was implementing the map it was not working ..anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you also add this line

```
<?= $this->Html->script('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true', false); ?>
```

and do you have in your layout the line

```
echo $this->fetch('script');
```

normally it is already there in your default.ctp .

Comment: yup i have already done this ..you can check my pastebin link

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a style sheet to go with the view.

If you don't give a height to the map container it will be 0 height.

Comment: nope... there is no stylesheet in the folder ... where can i see the css class so i can give height to that class

Comment: View source? If you are using the default CakePHP layout template you can add the styles to /app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css

Comment: I think you'll need to post the source of the generated page for some further help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried that plugin from 'marcferna', and followed the instructions. Changed it to HTTPS too, but it didn't work.

I am using this other Google Maps plugin now, which is working on my Cakephp 2.5.5

http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/12/21/googlemapsv3-cakephp-helper/